# Issue with ASM getMergedType and getCommonSuperClass

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-bytecode-asm

I use ASM to update the class stack map, but when asm `getMergedType`, the following exception occurs:

> java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.io.IOException: Resource not found for IntefaceImplA.

If without asm modify the class method, it does work fine.
I have defined two interfaces A and B: `IntefaceImplA` and 
`IntefaceImplB`.

My environment source code:

**IntefaceA.java**

```
public interface IntefaceA {
    void inteface();
}
```

**IntefaceImplA.java**

```
public class IntefaceImplA implements IntefaceA {
@Override
public void inteface() {

}
}
```

**IntefaceImplB.java**

```
public class IntefaceImplB implements IntefaceA {
@Override
public void inteface() {

}
}
```

**Test.java**

```
public class Test {
public IntefaceA getImpl(boolean b) {
    IntefaceA a = b ? new IntefaceImplA() : new IntefaceImplB();
    return a;
}
```

}

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String args[]) {
....
if (a instance of Test) {
..
...
}
}
}
```

After I compiled a runner jar, and delete the IntefaceImplA.class and IntefaceA.class manually from the jar. why i wanna to delete those classes files, since the spring always like to do this stuff.

the runner jar can be run normal without ASM, but use Asm will occur exception. since the asm wanna to getMergedType for IntefaceImplA and IntefaceImplB, but IntefaceImplA was deleted by me. 
After investigate the ASM ClassWriter source code i found below code:

```
protected String getCommonSuperClass(String type1, String type2) 
{
    ClassLoader classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
    Class c;
    Class d;
    try {
        c = Class.forName(type1.replace('/', '.'), false, classLoader);
        d = Class.forName(type2.replace('/', '.'), false, classLoader);
    } catch (Exception var7) {
        throw new RuntimeException(var7.toString());
    }

    if(c.isAssignableFrom(d)) {
        return type1;
    } else if(d.isAssignableFrom(c)) {
        return type2;
    } else if(!c.isInterface() && !d.isInterface()) {
        do {
            c = c.getSuperclass();
        } while(!c.isAssignableFrom(d));

        return c.getName().replace('.', '/');
    } else {
        return "java/lang/Object";
    }
}
```

Actually, I deleted the related class file, the classloader cannot find the class. but without asm the Program does work normal.
Should I enhance the override to the getCommonSuperClass method, if occur exception then return java/lang/Object for it? that's funny

Comment: 1.) Why do you “use ASM to update the class stack map”? There is no reason to update a stack map, unless you have performed other code transformations. But if you perform other code transformations, these transformations are the primary use of ASM, not updating the stack map. You should say something about the actual goal. 2) Why the hell do you delete classes which are still referenced by the code? “since the spring always like to do this stuff” is not a meaningful explanation.

Comment: since i need to insert some code in the run time.

Comment: since the spring boot deleted the code in order to decrease the jar size, when use tomcat as embed container. 
Why do you “use ASM to update the class stack map”?---  i need to insert some code in the run time.

Comment: When ASM tries to find the common super class of two types, it implies that both types are actually referenced by the code. If Spring Boot deleted code that is actually in use, I called it a serious bug, however, you clearly stated that **you** deleted the class file, so it’s not clear, how Spring Boot is to blame for that.

Comment: @Holger, The Spring boot embed container would be tomcat, jetty, undertow etc. not every related third-party jar pack into springboot jar. it's not a bug.

Comment: *Why do you delete a class file of a class that is still in use?*

Answer (score 6):

Generally, overriding `getCommonSuperClass` to use a different strategy, e.g. without loading the class, is a valid use case. As [it’s documentation](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/ClassWriter.html#getCommonSuperClass-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) states:

> The default implementation of this method *loads* the two given classes and uses the java.lang.Class methods to find the common super class. It can be overridden to compute this common super type in other ways, in particular without actually loading any class, or to take into account the class that is currently being generated by this ClassWriter, which can of course not be loaded since it is under construction.

Besides the possibility that either or both arguments are classes you are currently constructing (or changing substantially), it might be the case that the context of the code transforming tool is not the context in which the classes will eventually run, so they don’t have to be accessible via `Class.forName` in that context. Since `Class.forName` uses the caller’s context, which is ASM’s `ClassWriter`, it is even possible that ASM can’t access the class despite it is available in the context of the code using ASM (if different class loaders are involved).

Another valid scenario is to have a more efficient way to resolve the request by using already available meta information without actually loading the class.

But, of course, it is not a valid resolution to just return `"java/lang/Object"`. While this is indeed a common super type of every argument, it isn’t necessarily the right type for the code. To stay with your example,

```
public IntefaceA getImpl(boolean b) {
    IntefaceA a = b ? new IntefaceImplA() : new IntefaceImplB();
    return a;
}
```

the common super type of `IntefaceImplA` and `IntefaceImplB` is not only required to verify the validity of assigning either type to it, it is also the result type of the conditional expression, which must be assignable to the return type of the method. If you use `java/lang/Object` as common super type, a verifier will reject the code as it can’t be assignable to `IntefaceA`.

The original stackmap, very likely reporting `IntefaceA` as common super, will be accepted by the verifier as that type is identical to the method’s return type, so it can be considered assignable, even without loading the type. The test, whether either, `IntefaceImplA` and `IntefaceImplB`, is assignable to that specified common type, might be postponed to the point where these types are actually loaded and since you said, you deleted `IntefaceA`, this can never happen.

A method whose declared return type is absent, can’t work at all. The only explanation of your observation that “without asm the program does work normal”, is, that this method was never invoked at all during your test. You most probably created a time bomb in your software by deleting classes in use.

It’s not clear why you did this. Your explanation “since the spring always like to do this stuff” is far away from being comprehensible.

---

But you can use the overriding approach to get the same behavior as with the unmodified code. It just doesn’t work by return `java/lang/Object`. You could use

```
@Override
protected String getCommonSuperClass(String type1, String type2) {
    if(type1.matches("IntefaceImpl[AB]") && type2.matches("IntefaceImpl[AB]"))
        return "IntefaceA";
    return super.getCommonSuperClass(type1, type2);
}
```

Of course, if you deleted more class files, you have to add more special cases.

An entirely different approach is not to use the [`COMPUTE_FRAMES`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/ClassWriter.html#COMPUTE_FRAMES) option. This option implies that ASM will recompute all stack map frames from scratch, which is great for the lazy programmer, but implies a lot of unnecessary work if you are just doing little code transformations on an existing class and, of course, creates the requirement to have a working `getCommonSuperClass` method.

Without that option, the `ClassWriter` will just reproduce the frames the `ClassReader` reports, so all unchanged methods will also have unchanged stack maps. You will have to care about the methods whose code you change, but for a lot of typical code transformation tasks, you can still keep the original frames. E.g. if you just redirect method calls to signature-compatible targets or inject logging statements which leave the stack in the same state it was before them, you can still keep the original frames, which happens automatically. Note the existence of the [`ClassWriter(ClassReader,int)` constructor](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/ClassWriter.html#ClassWriter-org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader-int-), which allows an even more efficient transfer of the methods you don’t change.

Only if you change the branch structure or insert code with branches, you have to care for frames. But even then, it’s often worth learning how to do this, as the automatic calculation is quiet expensive while you usually have the necessary information already when doing a code transformation.